# fwrite becomes slow after long uptime

Tags: linux, io, fwrite, slowdown

Recently we had a production server up for 50+ days exhibit slow fwrite times. Sporadically, a single fwrite() would take 50 to 300 msec to complete (typically 300 to 2400 bytes). We spent a few days investigating, collecting stats, trying a number of things. Finally after rebooting the system the problem is gone and the server is running normal, as-expected operation. Here are some notes:

> -the system is a Xeon 2660 16-core with one HDD and one SSD, Ubuntu 12.04, 3.2.0-49-generic. The HDD is about 88% full and the SSD 75%. fstat() shows optimal HDD blocksize of 4096
>
> -the application software running on the system is two different executables that open, run, and close repeatedly, running for intervals from a minute to several hours, writing numerous wav files of various sizes on a continuous basis while they are running
>
> -both the HDD and SSD exhibited the issue. Writes to ramdisk were Ok

My question: is there any known issue where the Linux I/O interface can reach a point, over time, where a single flush or other I/O operation takes 50 or even 300+ msec to complete ?

We tried defragmenting both drives, setvbuf() variations, and non-blocking file descriptors (fcntl), without any change. After reboot we see wav file extents the same as before, ranging from 1 to 10 typically, depending on file size. The only hint seemed to be that we could occasionally catch a thread briefly showing long I/O wait time or in "uninterruptible sleep" state. For that we used htop (turning on Detailed CPU Usage) and this command:

```
     for x in `seq 1 1 100`; do ps -eo state,tid,pid,cmd | grep "^D"; echo "----"; sleep 0.25; done
```

which would (occasionally) show something like "flush-252:0"

We looked through [this thread on slow fwrites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168060/how-to-debug-very-slow-200-sec-fwrite-ftello-fclose) along with many other discussions but did not find anything that helped other than the usual "probably if you reboot it will go away". Which of course is good advice, but doesn't avoid the next occurrence.

After the reboot, we went on a hunt for any left-over file handles not being closed by those two (2) apps before terminating, and did find one case. My understanding is that should not have an effect.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, Jeff, but you probably want to install sysstat to get long term data (sar).  Then you want to collect iostat in particular wait i/o. Upgrade to the the latest kernel if you are not on it already.  If there is a firmware upgrade for the sdd consider installed that. https://serverfault.com/questions/341123/flush-processes-consume-too-much-of-cpu might be interesting.  Run smartct on your drives, hopefully your sdd is supported, and see how you are doing on total writes compared to life expectantcy.  Review dmesg

Comment: One thing you could do is grab a copy of the git repo for the kernel and see if git log -S fwrite turns up anything after whatever release you are on.  If you have an option swap on or both of the drives.  This would eliminate it as a root cause.

Comment: Also, this is not a programming question so post this on the server fault and/or unix & linux communities.

Comment: @Allan thanks we did review dmesg and found nothing since the system was booted way back and a few crashes from our apps during our investigation period (so after seeing the problem). For this system we cannot upgrade, it's used to support gov customers who need an exact copy of what they're using. iostat + sysstat -- yes I know, we haven't figured out yet how to install those on 12.04.  Working on it !

Comment: @Allan it might well be a programming question. I'm fully expecting it's something our software did incorrectly over a long period of time. As I noted, we did try many code changes to affect the problem, based on common advice found when searching for slow I/O performance

Comment: You want to review dmesg output for when you had service issues.  Do you log that to journald and/or syslog?

Comment: My swag would be kernel or hardware issue.  Are both drives on the same controller?  For those two processes look at /proc/$pid/fd (open file descriptors) to see if that lines up with what you expect.  Run `lsof` and/or `fuser` on those two processes, perhaps period snapshots.

Comment: @Allan we did carefully review dmesg and /var/log/syslog during the problem/investigation period (about a week)

Comment: @Allan yes both drives are on the same controller. We did run lsof commands, I'm trying to find those in our notes and add it to what we tried

Comment: Consider using `stat` instead of `state`.  It gives you a little more information, and if you continue this add matching iostat.  Timestamp both data sets so you can correlate it.

Comment: I know you said you could not upgrade... so start as soon possible on getting approval for a kernel upgrade.  Impossible tasks take longer to pull off (and sorry).  Please update question with kernel version `uname -r`, and maybe hardware info (controller, ssd, drive).  Is discard/trim enabled?  You said drives were slow so it may only matter if you have swap drive/file on the sdd.  You probably want noatime on sdd fs if you haven't now that we are talking about mounts.

Comment: @Allan can you clarify stat vs state ? Do you mean the stat() function, for example using another process (running on a different core) to periodically call stat() with output wav filenames ?

Comment: stat is multi-character process state, while state aka s is a single character process state.  It's covered in the man page you just have to dig for it.  You are interested in the D, S and W characters.  It may not actually tell you anything but better to have the data then not.

Comment: @Allan thanks.  I got you now, we should be using "stat" in the ps command, which would give some additional info along with the 'D' state (uninterruptible sleep) we were using